# azure db field name (column name) limitations

Tags: azure-sql-database

Anyone know where in the MS docs this kind of thing is defined (I'm specifically looking for what characters are allowed in the field names... IE unicode).  I haven't found hard docs yet, but the wording I've seen seems to indicate that it's collation dependent in the same way the tuples are.

If that's the case I'd love to see where in the docs that info is located. IE if it's in the azure docs / sql server docs etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm blown away that someone gave this a -1 without commenting.  The Azure docs don't lay this out anywhere that I can find and it's a super simple question (IE you either know the answer because it's been important to you or you don't)

Comment: More to the point I've scanned through most of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-servers-databases and haven't found anything remotely resembling this level of systems documentation and I'm not sure what the boundaries are between azure db and sql server.  IE are they the same thing with tweaks under the hood?  etcetc.  That link above is a decent general overview, but there's apparently no system level docs.

Comment: Would it help to rephrase the question as: "Where would the docs be for this particular attribute?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find any hard documentation on this subject, but the answer is yes.  It depends on system collation as documented here (the documentation does NOT actually answer the question though)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-transact-sql-information

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/working-with-collations-in-sql-azure/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2017

It looks like at this stage, this is really poorly documented in Azure.